# Problems with "link_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

NEW EDITING

With `resources :cases` in the `routes.rb` all these routing helpers work as expected (c is an instance of the model Case):

```
cases_path          # Index action
new_case_path       # New action
case_path(c)        # Show action
edit_case_path(c)   # Edit action
```

Changing `routes.rb` to this:

```
scope "/:area" do
  resources :cases
end
```

two routing helpers fail (see error below):

```
cases_path         # OK
new_case_path      # OK
case_path(c)       # Fail
edit_case_path(c)  # Fail
```

To make it works I need to change the last two helpers in:

```
cases_path                                 # OK
new_case_path                              # OK
case_path(c, :area => params[:area])       # OK
edit_case_path(c, :area => params[:area])  # OK
```

Why there is no need to give :area to the first two helpers and there is a need for the second two? It makes the code confusing...

OLD QUESTION

Initially I had this routes.rb:

```
resources :cases
```

and I could generate links of this type

```
example.com/cases/3
```

to show the case with ID = 3 with:

```
link_to("Show this case", @case)
```

Then I modified routes.rb to:

```
scope "/:area" do
  resources :cases
end
```

end the link_to above give me the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cases", :area=>#<Case id: 2,
```

It seems that rails does not get the :area from the parameters automatically. I could fix this forcing the area creating a link with

```
link_to("Show this case", case_path(params[:area], @item))
```

to obtain the link to

```
example.com/area1/cases/3
```

but I really don't like it. Am I doing something wrong? Why rails bring over the controller and the action but forget about the area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your ApplicationController:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  {:area => params[:area]}
end
```

You then don't have to manually set the :area option in your routing helpers

Comment: This works great within the scope, but linking to routes outside the scope (eg. root_path) include a `?area=1` as a querystring parameter (since the parameter doesn't exist in the route). How can you remove the parameter when linking outside the scope?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
link_to "Show this case", [:area, @case]
```

**EDIT** (remove the colon)

```
scope "/area" do
  resources :cases
end
```

**EDIT 2**

```
link_to "Show this case", case_path(@case, :area => :en)
```

If you specified `area` as argument you should always pass it.

Comment: This give the error `undefined method 'area_case_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003682ad8>:0x0000000360cbd0>`. The point is that I would like Rails to use the :area automatically.

Comment: The colon is necessary, see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params)

Comment: @Luke, you should describe it in your question :). Ok. I will edit my answer

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was not clear. The area variable can have any value. I would expect rails to add it automatically to links without having me to add manually all the time. I would like to create a link writing `link_to("Show this case", @case)` because Rails already know about the :area variable.